# Cant ping AWS IPV4 Public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am spinning up my first ever AWS EC2 server.

In my security groups I added a new group called inbound and allowed http and https traffic but still not working:

[image]

Comment: My guess is, you might have stopped & started the VM, which will change the public IP (unless it got EIP). Did you cross check you are using right IP? If IP is correct, what is the message you are seeing when you tried to access the url in browser?

Comment: took to long to respond

Comment: Did you check your instance public IP?

Comment: yes, I go to instance and look at the IPv4 public IP column and paste that IP into the borwser

Comment: What type instance this is? Stop opening 80 and 443 ports to ALL, instead use MYIP (for now). Restart the VM and try access again? What is listening on port 80? Apache httpd?

Comment: Its going to be a website, wouldn't I want port 80 and 443 open to all traffic so users can access it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169368/discussion-between-searayman-and-invoke-cloud).

Answer (score 0):

Ping works on ICMP protocol.

When you ping any server, ICMP protocol is used to send a `ICMP type 8 - Ping Request` message. The server replies back with a `ICMP type 0 - Ping Reply` message.

When you ping a server, say `google.com` from your EC2 instance, the server would send `ping reply` packets back to the instance. In order to accept those packets, you have to add a Custom ICMP rule with Type 0 message in the inbound rules of the security group attached to the instance.

Simply attaching the security group shown in the screenshot to the instance would not help. Also, it is in no way connected to port 80/443 and Apache at all!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

I followed the AWS instructions for allowing HTTPS and HTTP and created a new security group.

What i failed to do was add the new security group to the instance that I was running.

To do this select your instance then click Actions->networking-CHange Security Groups

Comment: Still I can't understand how you can ping to the instance with security ports as 80 and 443. ICMP is a different protocol altogether.

Comment: Unless you changed this security group's rule, it would not work! Maybe you attached some other security group to the instance which had ICMP Type 8 and Type 0 custom rules allowed on the inbound.